# Finding the number of solutions in a system of equations

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

Given:

$$M = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&7&0&3\\0&1&6&0&4\\0&0&0&1&2\\0&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
How many solutions does this system of equations have?
I am given four options:

A) One

B) Infinite

C) No solution

D) Three

I selected D but it was wrong as I simply counted the constants that are not zero, but obviously thats an incorrect way of finding the number of solutions. Does it have anything to do with leading and free variables?

Comment: System? Which system?

Comment: A system of equations would be $Mx=b$. You’re missing the RHS. Or is this an augmented matrix?

Comment: b option is it right?

Comment: There can only be 0, 1, or infinitely many solutions to any system of linear equations. Never 3.

Comment: @Joe: even in finite fields?

Comment: @Bernard, I know nothing about finite fields, so I’m guessing that means my comment is incorrect. I’m talking about linear maps from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: @Joe:  I guessed so. I was just jjoking. Cheers :)

Comment: @Bernard, I could tell. But I do appreciate the new knowledge that you gave me. I enjoy helping others, but the main reason I enjoy participating in this forum is for my own education! Best regards, Joe.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the last column are the right hand sides of the equations and the 4 columns to its left are the coefficients of the 4 unknowns.

The last equation is $0=0$, no contradiction. Only three relevant equations left:

We only have three pivots and column 3 has no pivot, so $x_3$ is a free variable. The other equations can then be back-substituted and we get infinitely many solutions in terms of the free parameter $x_3$. So B) is right.

D) can never be right for linear equations over the reals, it's always 0,1 or infinity (when we have a solution space of positive dimension, as here: a line).